# Аналог background-size: cover для img

Tags: html, css, css3

Можно ли сделать такое же позиционирование изображения в теге `img`,  как это делается с помощью `background-size: cover`?

Видел решения с помощью `object-fit`, также смотрел другие вырианты, но ни один из них не работает. Можно ли сделать без `object-fit`?

Comment: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11670874/3373603) предлагают много вариантов

Comment: @Ruslan_K, покажите мне хоть один рабочий вариант

Comment: допустим у изображений img разная высота. ни один пример не работает

Comment: Без `object-fit` только js. А чем он не устраивает?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670874/

Comment: @word вам покали рабочий вариант в ответах.

Comment: @word выберите правильный ответ.

Answer (score 19):

Свойство `object-fit` работает: скорее всего, вы неправильно его применяли или смотрели в IE. Ниже привожу пример правильного использования свойства:

```css
#bg {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#bg img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="bg">
        <img src="https://1000.tech/img/bg0.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Суть в том, чтобы `img` растягивать на всю высоту и ширину родительского блока, тогда свойство `object-fit: cover` сработает.